# Is there a way to open an image as bytes and return it to a jpg file?

Tags: python, byte

```
image = open(filepath, 'rb')
new_image = open("new_image_path.jpg", 'w', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
new_image.write(image.read().decode(encoding="ISO-8859-1"))
```

the new image I get is exactly the same if I open it in notepad++ but the new image is corrupted and can't be open for some reason.

Comment: You need to open `new_image` in `wb` mode to write binary data.

Answer (score 1):

You have to also use `'wb'` because it's not a text file. You should not decode and encode because it's not a text file. The functional code could be:

```
image = open(filepath, 'rb')
new_image = open("new_image_path.jpg", 'wb')
new_image.write(image.read())
```